# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot find a file named '...\bin\Debug\getAttribute.js' or an embedded resource with the id 'getAttribute.js'

Tags: .net, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I have some tests that use Geckodriver to run a test in Firefox. Today, Firefox updated to version 50 on my development machine. I saw this error:

`System.NotImplementedException : GET /session/ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff/element//attribute/ did not match a known command`

I updated to `geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64` and `selenium-dotnet-strongnamed-3.0.0` (for .NET 4.0), thinking maybe Selenium and GeckoDriver just needed to sync up with the latest version of Firefox.

Now, when I run this test, I see two things:

1. Firefox crashes with a breakpoint (...?) `A breakpoint has been reached.  (0x80000003) occurred in the application at location 0x6fa3ed40.`
2. `LightIntegration.Browser.QUnit.Firefox:
   OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot find a file named '...\bin\Debug\getAttribute.js' or an embedded resource with the id 'getAttribute.js'.`

I checked, and sure enough, there's no file with that name. There never has been. Was I supposed to download this file somewhere?

(For what it's worth, the same test passes when run in Chrome.)

Comment: The file `getAttribute.js` is supposed to be embedded in the library but it looks like it's missing from yours.

Comment: @FlorentB. Yep, the official strong named ZIP has a DLL that is missing that exact resource!

Answer (score 1):

As @FlorentB. suggested, my version of Selenium is missing that exact file as a resource.

On the left is [selenium-dotnet-strongnamed-3.0.0.zip](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.0/selenium-dotnet-strongnamed-3.0.0.zip), which I need to use because we [strong name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad(v=vs.110).aspx) our application.

On the right is [selenium-dotnet-3.0.0.zip](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.0/selenium-dotnet-3.0.0.zip)

[image: A comparison of the resources in the two files]
For some reason, `getAttribute.js` and `isDisplayed.js` are not included in the resources of the strong-named `WebDriver (3.0.0.0)` assembly.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3137 on Selenium's bug tracker. Hopefully it is fixed soon.

Comment: The issue will be fixed soon, and a 3.0.1 release will be cut to distribute it. I will make no promises on time frame, as the maintainer of the .NET bindings is traveling, and next week is a holiday week in his home country (Thanksgiving week in the USA).

Comment: As promised, the 3.0.1 release has been cut and the strong-named assemblies are available at http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html. Please feel free to raise another issue report if this one hasn't been fixed.