# selenium webdriver issue with Edge, cannot find a file ... or an embedded resource with the id 'isDisplayed.js'

Tags: selenium, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am trying to run my tests on Edge chromium, version 88.0.705.74. I am using the suitable version from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/
The browser gets launched and URL is navigated correctly but I get failure with following errors.

*Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot find a file named 'C:<path to my project>\bin\Debug\isDisplayed.js' or an embedded resource with the id 'isDisplayed.js'.*

Has anyone faced this issue or knows how to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: I find [a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685448/openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-cannot-find-a-file-named-bin-debug-get) and I think the issue is related with the selenium version you used. It looks like there's something wrong with your selenium library and some files in the library are missing. Which version of selenium are you using? Besides, are you using the same version of Edge WebDriver as your Edge browser?

Comment: Thanks Yu Zhou for your comment.. I am using Selenium.Webdriver version 3.141 and my edge driver version is 88.0.705, both are latest I believe.

Comment: I suggest that you can redownload and reinstall the Selenium server and Edge WebDriver then try again. If it still can't work, please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce** the issue. So that we can have a test and see how to help.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?